# Flask database in instance folder

Tags: python, flask

I am making a webapp project using flask framework, it is very simple a website with a single page that people can input words into, it works fine when I try to run it in the development vm that I am using, but when I try to `git clone` it into pi it creates the database in a folder called `instance` and accessing the webapp through the browser throws the error database is not found

To start the server without me doing anything I am using crontab

```
@reboot sleep 60 && sh /home/kali/webapp/start.sh
```

As for `start.sh`

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/kali/webapp.py runserver
```

`config.py`

```
import random 
import string 




class Config:

    SECRET_KEY = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(60))

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///_DB_.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = True 

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False 

config = {
    'dev' : DevelopmentConfig,
    'prod': ProductionConfig,
    }
```

As for `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask ,render_template,request ,url_for ,redirect ,send_from_directory
from webui import webui 
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_security import current_user
import os 
from models import db 
from models import mail
from config import config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config['dev'])
app.register_blueprint(webui)
db.init_app(app)
manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def initdb():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    db.session.commit()

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

I create the database by typing this command in the terminal

```
python3 app.py initdb
```

I tried to copy the data base outside the `instance` folder and inside the `webapp` folder but still got the same error

Comment: [Instance folder](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/config/#instance-folders) default location is `instance/`. You can use `open_instance_resource()` to open file from this folder, or `open_resource()` to open a resource file relative to root_path for reading.

Comment: The thing is when I create and run the webapp in a vm i don't get the instance folder but when i run it on pi over ssh I get the instance folder

Comment: Flask doesn’t create the instance folder automatically. [See here an example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/tutorial/factory/)